# aarch64 execute IRQ from EL1 in EL3

Tags: arm64, bare-metal, irq

Is it possible to execute an IRQ in EL3 (secure monitor) if IRQ was fired in EL1 context? E.g. I have entered EL1 via spsr_el3 (el1h selected) and after that setup a vector table with vbar_el1. Now, some IRQs I want to execute in EL3 mode. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called "Physical IRQ Routing", and is controlled via `scr_el3`. From [the manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest):

```
IRQ, bit [1]

        Physical IRQ Routing.

        0b0     When executing at Exception levels below EL3, physical IRQ
                interrupts are not taken to EL3.
                When executing at EL3, physical IRQ interrupts are not taken.

        0b1     When executing at any Exception level, physical IRQ interrupts
                are taken to EL3.
```

If you only want to handle *some* IRQs at EL3 and leave others to EL1, then you can simply handle that in the EL3 exception vector by setting:

- `spsr_el1` to `spsr_el3`.
- `elr_el1` to `elr_el3`.
- `elr_el3` to `vbar_el1` plus one of `0x80`/`0x280`/`0x480`/`0x680` depending on the state bits in `spsr_el3`.
- `spsr_el3 = (spsr_el3 & ~0xf00fff) | 0x3c5`. If your architecture has PAN support, you'll also have to check `spsr_el1` for the `SPAN` field, and if that's zero, OR `0x400000` into `spsr_el3`.

Comment: Don't you also have to set SPSR_EL3 to something like 0xc5, so Secure EL1 is entered with interrupts disabled?

Comment: @SimonWillcocks It's `0x3c5` even (full DAIF mask), but you're totally right.

Comment: Isn't bit 9 the Endianness state bit?

Comment: @SimonWillcocks only when returning to AArch32 state. For AArch64 state, endianness is controlled by `sctlr_elX` and bit 9 of the SPSR masks debug exceptions.

Comment: Of course you're right. Thanks. Note to self: ARM DDI 0487C.a C5-392

Comment: Can this work in practice? To know the interrupt source you first have to read GICC_IAR (assuming a GIC interrupt controller), which is a non-idempotent action. I have the impression that the "deferred" handler in EL1 would need to know to not read GICC_IAR again and instead look into some pre-agreed-upon memory location.

Comment: @MartinCejp I feel like one way or another, all GICC_IAR reads would have to be routed through and buffered by EL3. So if your EL1 kernel is either cooperating or can feasibly be patched, then I'd just replace the access(es) to GICC_IAR with an `smc` to return the top buffered interrupt. If you want this to work in the face of arbitrary and possibly untrusted kernels, then I think you'd have to unmap the real GIC from EL1 and virtualise it, which I don't think you can do without getting EL2 involved.

Comment: @Siguza What worked for me is to take advantage of the grouping feature of the GIC. You can configure it so that Group 0 interrupts = FIQ = EL3 and Group 1 interrupts = IRQ = EL1. The appropriate group can then be set for each interrupt line -- at least in case of the GICv2.